# Binding default input field values with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently writing an application in AngularJS, and I've stumbled across a problem while using ng-model with input fields.

In the case that a user does not enter any text in one input field, is there any way to bind a default value to the ng-model? A sample of the code is shown below:

```
<input class="formInput" placeholder="{{ testVar.hasName.name }}" type="text" id="nameUpdate" ng-model="upd.name">
```

The idea is a user will be updating data. The placeholder will show the existing data, in this case the name, and updating this field will bind to the model. However, if a user does not wish to update this particular field, how can I bind the existing value to the model? I've noticed giving the input a value="xyz" prevents the ng-model from working properly.

I should note defining this information in the controller as a default is not an acceptable solution, as the data within testVar will vary.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: why do you show existing data as placeholder, and not just as value in the textbox ?

Answer (score 0):

Not the best practice, but you can init a default value with the help of `ng-init`:

```
<input class="formInput"
       placeholder="{{testVar.hasName.name}}"
       type="text"
       id="nameUpdate"
       ng-init="upd.name='defaultTextHere'"
       ng-model="upd.name">
```

Comment: So this seems to be what I'm looking for, but is it possible to bind a variable to this? ng-init=" '{{testVar.hasName.name}}' " holds the string correctly, however just ng-init="{{testVar.hasName.name}}" does not send the value to my controller.

Comment: Gave it a try, printing upd.name in an alert gives undefined?

Comment: Still undefined :(